# How to Make Event Plot using Python Bokeh Library?

Tags: python, bokeh

I am trying to make event plot using Bokeh Library. I know it is possible using [matplotlib.pyplot.eventplot](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.eventplot.html), But I need more interactivity features that is available in Bokeh

I came across the screenshot of such a chart in this [Website](https://matthewrocklin.com/blog/work/2018/07/08/dask-dev). So it must be possible in Bokeh.
[image: Bokeh Event Plot]

How do I make a similar plot using Bokeh Library?

Comment: The figure you have shared is generated using the [`dask package`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) which internally uses `bokeh`. Maybe this is allready healpful fro you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is very basic. You can use the `rect()` function of the figure object, where you have to define `x`, `y` and `width`. In your case the figure should have an `x-axis` in `datetime`-format. The width is your duration of on task.

**Minimal example**

```
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource

df = pd.DataFrame({'y':[1, 2, 3, 4], 
                   'start':[0, 1, 1, 10], 
                   'duration':[1, 2, 1, 5], 
                   'color':['green', 'red', 'blue', 'red']
                  })
>>>df
   y  start  duration  color
0  1      0         1  green
1  2      1         2    red
2  3      1         1   blue
3  4     10         5    red

p = figure(
    width=350,
    height=350,
    title="Task Stream",
    toolbar_location="above",
    x_axis_type="datetime",
)

p.rect(
    source=ColumnDataSource(df),
    x="start",
    y="y",
    width="duration",
    height=0.4,
    fill_color="color",
    line_color="color",
)
show(p)
```

**Output**

[image: Basic example for streaming data]

**Comment**

As I mentionend in the comment, the figure you have shared is generated using the [`dask package`](https://docs.dask.org/en/latest/dataframe.html) which internally uses `bokeh`. They use the same idea I described above, but of course the dask project offers much more than this on figure and maby solves more than one problem you have.

Comment: Thanks. This can solve my problem. But Actually I was trying to make an event plot where there no duration column in the data. There is only a list of timestamps in the data. Is there any option in Bokeh to plot vertical lines just like matplotlib or the only option is to use small constant width rectangles?

Comment: If a costant is enough you can write `width=2`  in `p.rect()` which will use the same width for all elements in CDS. Any other integer is also possible. It's on you.